# Subsequence of list that adds up to 21

Tags: list, python-3.x, backtracking, subsequence

Using Python, how would I go about returning a subsequence of a list of positive integers that add up to 21.

for example, for the list:

```
x = [5, 6, 7, 10, 11]
```

the subsequence would be:

```
[[5, 6, 10], [10, 11]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Backtracking` to generate all possible cases although the complexity would be high for large no of elements i.e `O(2^n)` for n elements in the list.

At each index in the recursive call we can either choose the current element or choose to ignore it, thereby going through all possible cases.

Python code :

```
list = [5, 6, 7, 10, 11]

def solve(index, sum, ans):
    if(index == len(list)):
        if(sum == 21):
            print(*ans)
    else:
        ans.append(list[index])
        solve(index+1, sum+list[index], ans)
        ans.pop(-1)
        solve(index+1, sum, ans)

ans = []
solve(0, 0, ans)
```

Link to solution on Ideone : http://ideone.com/P5HnfU